# I'm looking to pull the Time of an event, (Not Date) out of Google Calendar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Google Calendar to Google Sheets and source pulls from events[i].getStartTime() and this only pulls the date, I am looking to pull just the Start Clock Time.

I've looked all over and cannot find the code to pull this from Google Calendar.

```
var details = [[
  events[i].getTitle(),
  events[i].getLocation(),
  events[i].getDescription(),
  events[i].getStartTime(),
  events[i].getDateCreated()
]];
var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);
```

Actual result would be to get the Start "TIME" of the events on the calendar to Google Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to put the start time of event to the Spreadsheet.

  - In this case, it is the time which is not the date.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer?

`getStartTime()` returns the date object. So the information of time is also included. From this situation, when your script is modified, how about the following modifications?

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the time is shown by setting the cell format using `setNumberFormat()`.

#### Modified script:

```
var details = [[
  events[i].getTitle(),
  events[i].getLocation(),
  events[i].getDescription(),
  events[i].getStartTime(),
  events[i].getDateCreated()
]];
var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
sheet.getRange(row,4,1,1).setNumberFormat("HH:mm:ss"); // Added
range.setValues(details);
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the time is set as a string using `Utilities.formatDate()`.

#### Modified script:

```
var details = [[
  events[i].getTitle(),
  events[i].getLocation(),
  events[i].getDescription(),
  Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss"), // Modified
  events[i].getDateCreated()
]];
var range = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5);
range.setValues(details);
```

### Note:

- This is a simple modification. So please modify it for your situation.

### References:

- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)
- [formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  I had added this line in the second example and then some how all my dates got changed to times.  So, I took the line back out and still all dates are shown as time format.  It's kind of frustrating as it showed up correctly the first time.  After rerunning it, it's not the same.  As you can see, the Date and created are now as time formats and I can't get it to go back.

EVENT / SHOW VENUE / LOCATION NOTES DATE CREATED
WRG LIVE Pickup 206pc Sheraton Grand Nashville Downtown, 623 Union St, Nashville, TN 37219, USA Event Contact: STACEY FLEISCHER 18:00:00 13:56:06

Comment: @Cort Events Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your replying, I could confirm that you tested the script of pattern 2. But I cannot understand about your current situation. So in order to correctly confirm your current situation, can you provide your current script and sample Spreadsheet for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. Of course, please remove your personal information. By the way, how about the script of pattern 1?

Comment: I was able to get it back. I closed the browser and all and then brought up a new Sheets doc. So, it worked after that. I used the second example, the first didn't work. Is there a way to show the time instead of military time to 8AM, 8:30AM and so on? I really appreciate your help Tanaike!

Comment: @Cort Events Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. About your new question, if you want to put the value like `8AM` and `8:30AM`, please modify `"HH:mm:ss"` of `Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "HH:mm:ss")` to `"hha"` and `"hh:mma"`, respectively. In this case, please run the script after you set the cell format as the text. Is my understanding of your new question correct?

Comment: Sorry, my computer here rebooted and I lost this location.  It took me hours to find it.  LOL  I found an issue with the script.  For some reason, it is pulling the event times an hour off.  If I have a time of 4pm, it brings it up as 3pm.  The event dates and times are pulling as CST, but it is not displaying correct.

Does this line need to be changed some how to bring up the local time?
var details=[[events[i].getTitle(), events[i].getLocation(), events[i].getDescription(), events[i].getStartTime(), Utilities.formatDate(events[i].getStartTime(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "hh:mma")]];

Comment: also there was no accept button for me to click on that answer.

Comment: I just did both.  Thank you.